# Creating a new child process when old one is terminated in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, waitpid

I've included code that creates a series of child processes to divide the work for a task. There's a random chance for it to terminate (handled by the word_count function from which it calls abort()) and on this event, it should create a new child process to replace it. However, the program is being blocked on the read. I know this code is messy, but I want understand the problem before cleaning it up.

```
    int pipes[nChildProc][2]; //pipe fd[0] is read end, fd[1] is write end
    long child_f_size = fsize / nChildProc;
    pid_t pids[nChildProc];

    //start dividing the work among child processes
    for(int i = 0; i < nChildProc; ++i) {
        //srand(time(NULL));
        //int crash = ((rand() / RAND_MAX + 1.0) < crashRate) ? 1 : 0;
        if(pipe(pipes[i]) != 0) {
            printf("Failed to create pipe.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        pid_t pid = fork();
        FILE *child_fp;
        pids[i] = pid;

        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Failed to create child process.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid == 0) { //child process
            count_t temp_count = readFromFile(child_fp, fsize, child_f_size, char* name, int i, int nChildProc);

            //IPC with the main process
            if(write(pipes[i][1], &temp_count, sizeof(temp_count)) == -1)
                printf("failed to write to pipe.\n");

            close(pipes[i][1]);
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            exit(0); //deallocate process' memory space
        }
    }

    //wait for a children to finish
    int ret, status, i = 0;
    while(wait(NULL) != -1) { // while there are children to wait on
        ret = waitpid(pids[i], &status, WUNTRACED);

        if(ret == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        if(ret != 0) {// didn't exit normally
            if(pipe(pipes[i]) != 0) {
                printf("Failed to create pipe.\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            pid_t pid = fork();
            FILE *child_fp;
            pids[i] = pid;

            if(pid < 0) {
                printf("Failed to create child process.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else if(pid == 0) { //child process
                count_t temp_count = readFromFile(child_fp, fsize, child_f_size, char* name, int i, int nChildProc);

                //IPC with the main process
                if(write(pipes[i][1], &temp_count, sizeof(temp_count)) == -1)
                    printf("failed to write to pipe.\n");

                close(pipes[i][1]);
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                exit(0); //deallocate process' memory space
            }
        }

        i = (i + 1) % nChildProc;//loop back to detect more processes that were terminated
    }

    long bytes;
    count_t temp;
    temp.linecount = 0;
    temp.wordcount = 0;
    temp.charcount = 0;

    //add up all the values from children to count
    printf("time to read.\n");
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < nChildProc; ++j) {
        if((bytes = read(pipes[j][0], &temp, sizeof(temp))) < 0) {//blocked here
            printf("Failed to read from pipe {%d}.\n", j);
            exit(1);
        }

        if(bytes != 0) {
            count.linecount += temp.linecount;
            count.wordcount += temp.wordcount;
            count.charcount += temp.charcount;
        }

        close(pipes[j][1]);
        close(pipes[j][0]);
    }
```

Comment: Great code! But Please use `function()` s

Comment: the pids array is not updated in the correct spot, you are saving 0 in the copy of the child process?

Comment: I mean you should move pids[i] = pid; outside the else if block into parent process territory.

Comment: @JoCyber The function is to large to read.. Most people will split it up.

Comment: breaking code up into functions helps you understand as well as express what's going on - so deferring breaking up your code into functions "you understand what's going wrong" doesn't make sense.

Comment: the wait stuff are suspicious, check out man page: "on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child", you need to fix tracking the status of children. Maybe get rid of the wait and (re)fork stuff for now, make sure it works and add tracking later as a function

Comment: to avoid problems, now and later, always match the syntax of a called function.  For instance, the function `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues jump out:

1. `if(ret != 0) {// didn't exit normally` you've confused `ret` (which is the pid) for `status` (which is the exit code of the child)
2. You can't call wait on a process twice, since calling wait allows the system to release the resources associated with the process. You have several options on how to rewrite this code:

```
        while(wait(NULL) != -1) { // while there are children to wait on
            ret = waitpid(pids[i], &status, WUNTRACED);
```

One easy way is to use `wait` then lookup in the array which index it belongs to.

```
    while((pid = wait(&status)) {
        if (pid == -1) {  // no children to wait on
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nChildProc; ++i) {
            if (pid == pids[i]) break;
        }
        if (i >= nChildProc) {
            unexpected_pid_do_something_smart();
        }
        // Leave the rest of the loop the same
```

Note: I didn't compile or test the above code.

Comment: Thanks, man. I knew the waits were an issue but had no idea how to write it differently. I'll test this out in a bit.

Comment: It seems to work now. I had to modify what you wrote slightly but you helped me see what the problem was, which is even better. Thanks, bro.